# The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file is not valid or does not exist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, restore, certificate

I'm trying to perform a restore of a database from a different server onto my localhost server .That database is encrypted (the bak file ) ,so I have to decrypt it ,that's fine I have all the cert files and the password ,but for some reason I'm still getting the following error :

`The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file is not valid or does not exist; or you do not have permissions for it.`

This is the code I'm executing:

```
      CREATE CERTIFICATE [Certificate1] 
FROM FILE = 'C:\Location of the certs'
WITH PRIVATE KEY ( 
    FILE = 'C:\Location of the certs' ,   
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password'
);
```

PS. I'm no expert at backups and restores .

Comment: Are you giving the path a file name (not just a folder)? The instructions on that aren't extremely clear.

Comment: @JacobH Yes I have the filename included in the path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps that I had to take to restore the encrypted database onto a different server(localhost).

1.Create the certificates :

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE [CertficateName] 
FROM FILE = 'C:\FolderName\NameOfCert.cer'
WITH PRIVATE KEY ( 
    FILE = 'C:\FolderName\NameOfCertKey.key' ,   
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'YourPassword'
);
```

2.

```
USE Master ;
Open Master Key Decryption by password = 'YourPassword'
Backup master key to file = 'C:\SQL FodlerName\MasterKeyName.key'
        ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'YourPassword';
    GO
```

3.Restore Master Key

```
Use master 
    restore master key
    FROM FILE = 'C:\FolderName\MasterKeyName.key'
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'YourPassword'
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'YourPassword'
```

4.
This is the last step you ,be careful at this stage as it took me a while to get that each command needs to be run separately :

```
Alter Database [DatabaseName]
SET SINGLE_USER WITH
ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Next run it separatly

```
USE MASTER
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'YourPassword';
```

Next command run separatly

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DatabaseName] FROM DISK = 'C:\Folder\FULL\NameoftheBakFilethat ourAreRestoring.BAK' 
WITH Replace , STATS = 5
```

Do not forget to set back to Multi-User mode the Dabase.

Comment: How do you resolve the error? I got the same exact error on your first step, importing existing cert and key.