# Permissions issue in Docker SQL Server 2017 while restoring certificate

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2017, docker, certificate

Docker SQL Server 2017 container @latest. Using `master` database.

The error I am facing is the following:

`[S00019][15208] The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file is not valid or does not exist; or you do not have permissions for it.`

The closest thing I have found to this exact question is [this issue on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285844/create-a-cert-from-cer-and-p7b-in-sql-server-2017-linux-image-running-in-a-doc?rq=1). However the answer doesn't work for me. [This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211777/issue-restoring-certificate-to-sql-server-when-different-service-account-used) has a similar answer.

I have also tried the instructions [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207632/77028), and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207168/the-certificate-asymmetric-key-or-private-key-file-is-not-valid-or-does-not-ex/207632).

So going through the parts of the error:

1. I have recreated the files twice, so I don't think it's the "invalid" part. And it's obviously not the "does not exist" part (if I put in the wrong password, it tells me it's the wrong password).
2. I have backed up and restored the SMK and Master Key without issue, so I don't think it's the permissions issue. The files have the exact same permissions.

I can't get the certificate to restore no matter what I try. I have searched the [GitHub issues](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues) to no avail so I don't think it's a bug. I must be doing something wrong.

Relevant code:

```
--on Prod
BACKUP CERTIFICATE sqlserver_backup_cert
TO FILE = '/var/opt/mssql/certs/sqlserver_backup_cert.cer'
WITH PRIVATE KEY (
    FILE = '/var/opt/mssql/certs/sqlserver_backup_cert.key',
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'foobar'
    )
```

```
--on Test
CREATE CERTIFICATE sqlserver_backup_cert
FROM FILE = '/var/opt/mssql/certs/sqlserver_backup_cert.crt'
WITH PRIVATE KEY (
    FILE = '/var/opt/mssql/certs/sqlserver_backup_cert.key',
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'foobar'
    )
```

It's noteworthy that `/var/opt/mssql/certs` is a Docker volume. However I have also tried creating my own directory inside the container and using `docker cp`. No change.

Comment: There is now a [GitHub issue for this](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/505).

Comment: Are the UID etc for the docker etc the same? It looks like an issue where the user under which the SQL Server service doesn't have access to the .key file

Comment: Yes that's what I'd assume it is, but all the solutions say "check NTFS perms"–of which, there are none, in this case. Perms are 0744. The UID will not be the "same" necessarily, although in this case, both users are UID=1000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the code shown under "Relevant code:" (in the question) the *exact* code being executed, as in copied and pasted into here and not re-typed? I ask because the file extension on the **sqlserver_backup_cert** file is different between the `BACKUP` and `CREATE` (i.e. restore) statements. It is backed-up as **.cer** but then you are looking for **.crt** in the `CREATE`.

Also, have you tried skipping files altogether and using hex bytes (i.e. a `VARBINARY` literal)? You would do the following:

**On Prod**

```
SELECT CERTENCODED(CERT_ID(N'sqlserver_backup_cert')) AS [CertificateAndPublicKey],
       CERTPRIVATEKEY(CERT_ID(N'PrivateKeyTest'),
                      'new_password_for_extract(A)',
                      'current_password(B)') AS [PrivateKey];
```

**On Test**

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE [sqlserver_backup_cert]
    FROM BINARY = {output of CERTENCODED}
    WITH PRIVATE KEY (
        BINARY = {output of CERTPRIVATEKEY},
                 DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'new_password_for_extract(A)',
                 ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'current_password(B)'
                     );
```

**UPDATE**

O.P. has confirmed that the issue was indeed the filename extension mismatch.

Comment: Thank you, I will check.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look at this system... Larger systems on fire. But I will go ahead and award you and we can work through it later. :)

Comment: In point of fact it was the `.cer` vs. `.crt` issue. I've made an appointment with the optometrist. ;)

Comment: @ChaimEliyah Sometimes it just takes a 2nd pair of eyes :-). Have you tried the other approach, using the `VARBINARY` literal? I would actually recommend that and stop messing with files in the first place. That way you can have fully-contained rollout scripts with no external dependencies.

Comment: Okay I will give that a shot when I tackle the restore portion. And yes! L'shana tovah!!! :)

Comment: @ChaimEliyah Thanks, and once you get a chance to do the inline version I think you will prefer it. At this point I think we can clean up our comments here. I have already removed most of mine and will remove the rest after you have deleted yours. I will also add a comment to that GitHub issue regarding my 2 suggestions. Take care!